# assign a string under a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a string like this.

```
"457, 1480-(5, 12), 83-(1, 2), 484, 484-(2, 3, 8)"
```

I want to assign a heading number for each element only when there are parentheses.
My desired output is this

```
"457, 1480-5, 1480-12, 83-1, 83-2, 484, 484-2, 484-3, 484-8"
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've entirely answered the question but I've change the first list to the second list (in a data frame).

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(stringi)

  df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~column,
    "457, 480-(5, 12), 483-(1, 2), 484, 484-(2, 3, 8)"
  )
```

The following separates the parts using the comma as a delimiter, removes the brackets, then I've used {stringi} to reformat the numbers. I've created 2 extra columns, one for the main 3 digit number (main_number) and one for the subset number (denoted by -). After reformatting I've taken the main_number if there was no subset and for the rest, pasted the two columns main_number and subset.

```
  df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(split_out = strsplit(as.character(column), ",")) %>%
    tidyr::unnest(split_out) %>% 
    select(-column) %>% 
    mutate(split_out = str_remove(split_out, "[()]"),
           split_out = str_trim(split_out), # has trailing whitespace
           main_number = case_when(stri_length(split_out) == 3 ~ split_out,
                                   TRUE ~ substr(split_out, 1, str_locate(split_out, "-") -1)),
           subset = case_when(str_detect(split_out, "-") == TRUE ~ substr(split_out,
                                                                          str_locate(split_out, "-"), # where - appears + 1
                                                                          stri_length(split_out)), # the end of the string
                              stri_length(split_out) < 3 ~ paste0("-", split_out),
                              TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
    fill(main_number, .direction = c("down")) %>% # fill down so the main number is copied down 
    mutate(new_number = case_when(is.na(subset) ~ main_number,
                                  TRUE ~ paste0(main_number, subset)
                                  )) %>% 
    select(new_number)
```

Comment: thank you so much. Unfortunately, I have a large data set and stri_length(split_out)  is not always 3. I update the question. can you help me with the updated question?

Comment: What is the range for the main numbers (for example: 410-4000) and the subset (for example: 1-20). This will give a better idea of what to set the numbers to as it may be that you need to change case_when(stri_length(split_out) => 3 to mean if it is equal to or greater than 3 characters.